# Cannot remove dynamic event listeners

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

When using a regular function to bind to an event, I can remove it without problems. But when using a dynamic list of context functions, I cannot remove listeners for those.

Here's a simplified version of an entire test application:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function CustomEventEmitter() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(CustomEventEmitter, EventEmitter);

var obj = new CustomEventEmitter();

var onError, exists = false;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    onError = function (err) {
        console.log(err, i);
    };

    if (exists) {
        obj.removeListener('error', onError);
        exists = false;
    }

    obj.on('error', onError);
    exists = true;
}
```

It will result in:

`Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added.
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

because the call to `removeListener` doesn't really remove the listener.

How one is supposed to remove dynamic listeners like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! When you do

```
var onError = function (err) {
    console.log(err, i);
};
```

that assigns a new function to the `onError` variable. Since you do that in between `obj.on('error', onError);` and `obj.removeListener('error', onError);`, the one you are trying to remove is not the same one you added. So nothing gets removed.

If you do this:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function CustomEventEmitter() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(CustomEventEmitter, EventEmitter);

var obj = new CustomEventEmitter();

var exists = false;
var onError;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (exists) {
        obj.removeListener('error', onError);
        exists = false;
    }

    onError = function (err) {
        console.log(err, i);
    };

    obj.on('error', onError);
    exists = true;
}
```

it'll do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm afraid I may have over-simplified my example. I have updated the example to reflect more accurately what I am doing in reality. How one can solve it for a dynamic list of listeners?

Comment: Nevermind, I have reverted it back, because it would make a different question.